# jQuery .data() does not update HTML5 data attributes

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, custom-data-attribute

I am trying to add a "**data-bind**" attribute to a div using jQuery as follows:

```
var messageViewModel = {
    data: ko.observable({   
        message: response.message, 
        sendDateFmted: response.sendDateFmted, 
        messageId: response.messageId
    })
     };

$("<div>",{
    class:"messageToAndFromOtherMember"
}).data("bind", "template: { name: 'message-template', data: data }").appendTo("#messagesToAndFromOtherMember");

ko.applyBindings(messageViewModel);
```

"**data-bind**" is required by KnockoutJs. However all I get is this empty div:

```
<div class="messageToAndFromOtherMember"></div>
```

Notice there is no such attribute as `data-bind` and therefore the div remains empty...

Comment: +1 for a usefull question as this is a common issue. When writing data using `.data()` it will not update any elements, it will merely store data in memory for that element in a key-value pair format, in your case `bind`. being the key and the rest being the value. See the [data-documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/) for more details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jQuery's [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) stores the values in-memory and uses `data-*` attributes for initialization. You may want to stick by setting it at element creation.

```
$("<div/>", {
  class: "messageToAndFromOtherMember",
  "data-bind": "template: { name: 'message-template', data: data }"
}).appendTo("#messageToAndFromOtherMember");
```

Comment: +1 for explaining that `.data()` stores the values in memory. It can be confusing sometimes as when calling `.data()` it will read data attributes of elements and store them in memory and as far as I know it will use the in-memory storage for any consecutive call thereafter. When updating the data using `.data()` it will not write back to the elements but merely update the in-memory stored data.

Answer (score 2):

Alexander's answer is definitely correct, in the general sense, but I couldn't help but notice that in your specific example you seem to be adding messages to your code by creating a new binding scope for each message. If this is the case, I think you are using Knockout incorrectly (if not, let me know and I will just remove this).

If you are getting new messages from a server, and just trying to display the list of them on the page, a much better structure would be to use an [ObservableArray](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html), and simply push new messages to it. The standard knockout binding will automatically add the new messages to your html, without the mess of creating a new binding scope, and a completely independent viewmodel for the new message. You can see this in action in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/F2ukz/1/).

Here is the rather contrived ViewModel:

```
var ViewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.messages = ko.observableArray();
    self.newMessage = ko.observable('');
    self.addMessage = function() {
        var message = new Message({ message: self.newMessage()});
        self.newMessage('');
        self.messages.push(message);
    };
};
```

Comment: Tyrsius, I am rather new to KO. Thanks a lot for your reply. I will definitely consider this alternative.

Comment: @balteo I figured. We are all new at some point. I would take some time to go through the [knockout tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/), they might help you understand the pattern a little better.

Comment: I will do so. Thanks for the link.