# how to write knock out Data bind event dynamically in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

```
var $butt = $('<input/>').attr({
    type: 'button',
    value: data.styleData,
    id: butnId,
    data - bind: event: {
        click: $parent.submitPopUp
    }
});
```

it shows an error

Comment: It would be very useful to know exactly what the error says instead of just saying "It shows an error".

Comment: property `data - bind` is invalid attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `attr` in a wrong way
You should try this,

```
$(function(){
  var butt = $('<input/>',{
      type: 'button',
      value: "button",
      id: "btnId",
      "data-bind": 'event: {click: $parent.submitPopUp}'
   }).appendTo('body');
});
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/JAGLu/

Read [Best way to add DOM elements with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202269/best-way-to-add-dom-elements-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't use `data - bind` directly. It's not valid variable name or attribute name because of the `space`

but you can do instead :

```
var $butt = $('<input/>').attr({
    type: 'button',
    value: "button",
    id: "btnId",
    "data-bind": 'event: {click: $parent.submitPopUp}'
});
```

Kindly check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673369/jquery-data-does-not-update-html5-data-attributes)

Comment: Hmm, but I think this is not the way to add any `element` in `DOM`.

Comment: in the question @hemanth didn't write anything about adding the element. simple he can use this "$('selector').append($butt);"